# bash shell script get substring from string containing quotes

Tags: bash-scripting

I have a file named `stuff.txt`. There are multiple lines in that file. This is one of the lines in that file `"somevalue": "4.2.1"`. I'm creating a shell script to get the value between the second set of double quotes (4.2.1). Here's what I have in my shell script so far:

`substringVal=$(grep '\"somevalue\": \"' stuff.txt)`

this snippet stores the value `"somevalue": "4.2.1"` in my variable `substringVal` but I want `substringVal` to contain `4.2.1` only. I don't know how long the substring will be so I can't just take a substring starting at a certain index for a certain amount of characters.

I've looked at `awk` but I haven't been able to get it to work for me. If anyone could point me in the right direction on how to modify my command in my shell script to get the substring from the line I'm grepping for I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the file JSON? Does it contain other syntax elements or really just lines with two quoted fields separated by `: `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked this way for me:

```
substringVal=$(grep '\"somevalue\": \"' stuff.txt)
echo $substringVal

"somevalue": "4.2.1"
echo $substringVal | awk -F": " '{print $2}' | sed 's/\"//g'
4.2.1
```

So the awk command skips all until the  ": ""-separator. And sed removes the last doble-quote.

Comment: You can also get rid of all the quotes with `tr -d '"'` first. I'd do that in one go: `substringVal=$(grep somevalue stuff.txt | tr -d '"' | awk -F': ' '{print $2}')`

Comment: @Bernd works as asked, upvoted and marked as accepted answer. Thanks a lot!